# Can I get the user's top percentile, for tags, using the API?

Tags: support, api, tags

this is the data I receive when asking for a user data with the Stack Exchange API:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "badge_counts": {
      "bronze": 27,
      "silver": 12,
      "gold": 0
    },
    "account_id": 1995901,
    "is_employee": false,
    "last_modified_date": 1523971782,
    "last_access_date": 1524655618,
    "age": 30,
    "reputation_change_year": 326,
    "reputation_change_quarter": 123,
    "reputation_change_month": 123,
    "reputation_change_week": 42,
    "reputation_change_day": 2,
    "reputation": 1515,
    "creation_date": 1351694267,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "user_id": 1788884,
    "accept_rate": 50,
    "location": "Israel",
    "website_url": "http://www.facebook.com/NeilKalman",
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788884/thatkookooguy",
    "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYlfy.gif?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name": "Thatkookooguy"
  }],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 300,
  "quota_remaining": 267
}
```

But I'm trying to obtain this statistic:

[image]

getting the percentage and tags that percentage is relevant for.

anyway of getting that through the API?

I want to create a little widget to embed this data in my digital CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the API cannot do this.  Refer to [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and you'll note that there is no method that can be used to compute a user's tag percentile<sup>‡</sup>.

Also, it's not clear exactly how it's calculated:

1. Many tags are not eligible. (Number of questions? Total tag score?)
2. It *might* be that users with less than 200 rep are not counted.

Anyway, you can **get the percent standing of all of your (eligible) tags with this SEDE query:**

[data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given-user...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given-user-in-all-of-his-eligible-tags?UserId=1788884)

Which returns results like:

[image: SEDE reults]

Or you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag?UserId=1788884&TagName=angularjs), which returns your percent and ranking for a single tag.

Alas, SEDE does not have an API, but:

- Percentile data changes slowly.  You could/should cache this in your app and just update it every 1 to 6 weeks. (Note that SEDE updates weekly and other data sources update quarterly.)
- You [can run a SEDE query in Google's *BigQuery*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/) -- which *does* have an API.

---

<sup>‡</sup> Technically, you could do it for ***low traffic*** tags by downloading every question and answer for that tag.  But this would take a while and also quickly bust your quota.